Sitecore headless on local environment experience editor facing issue
When I open the Sitecore headless page in the experience editor, it does not load the page on the first try; it needs to be refreshed to load.
The below error is coming when the experience editor is not loading
▸ Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sc103headlesssc.dev.local/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=%7b9B644D11-2FCC-42FC-892F-C3946FB35D76%7d&sc_lang=en&sc_version=1&sc_site-movie-matrix' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted websocket.js:64 to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://http//localhost:3000/_next/webpack-hmr. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
▸▸ Error was not caught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
>
at init (websocket.js:64:18)
at connectHMR (websocket.js:70:5)
at pageBootrap (page-bootstrap.js:23:31)
at eval (next-dev.js:25:43)
[Deprecation] Listener added for a 'DOMSubtreeModified' mutation event. Support for this event type has been removed, and this event will no longer be fired. See <URL> for more information.
hydration-error-info.js:63


When the page is opened in the Experience editor, it opens over HTTPS and tries to call the sitecore Nextjs front-end instance, which runs on HTTP. So how do we configure Nextjs instance on HTTPS in this case, or is there any alternative way to solve this issue for local environment.

Mixed Content issue usually happen when your request is over the secured protocol (HTTPS) and the resources you are using are served over HTTP.
You can check with these things on your page.

Check the images.
Check the assets like CSS and JS should always use a relative path.
Check with the blank page with no resource in it and see if you get the same error.

Hope this helps.

When the page is opened in the Experience editor, it opens over HTTPS and tries to call the sitecore Nextjs front-end instance, which runs on HTTP. So how do we configure Nextjs instance on HTTPS in this case, or is there any alternative way to solve this issue for local environment.

Check this https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/latest/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--connecting-a-next-js-jss-app-to-sitecore-editors.html#update-the-sitecore-configuration-patch-for-the-jss-app

Find section 'Update the Sitecore configuration patch for the JSS app'

Configuration from the document is already there
